# Dependent Drop down on Google Form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Good day Ma'am/Sir, So I have a Google form from google drive, and a google sheets that contain the records for the dependent drop down.

I have 3 dropdown fields that dependent to each other, these are
-PROVINCE
-TOWN/CITY
-BARANGAY/DISTRICT

How this will work, If I select one record on "PROVINCE", the drop down list of "TOWN/CITY" will automatically populated depend on the selected item on the "PROVINCE". After that the drop down list of "BARANGAY/DISTRICT" will automatically populated depend on the selected item on the "TOWN/CITY" under "PROVINCE".

This are the screen shots of my for and library of address here in Philippines.
[Form for encoding the profile of user, with dependent drop down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Mh9.jpg)
[1st Sample list of provinces and town/city in google drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHics.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Array. Make one separate sheet to store all values. The category, sub-category 1 and sub category 2 will be in one column.

Comment: Thank you Mr/Ms. @user8969716 I follow your suggestion, I add all the records in one column in a new sheet, then how to do the array script on this ?

Comment: Do you have a sample?